# Ruby query need to update

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

Relationship:

> account has_many users
>
> user has_one sima

primary_partner_id is "account_id" which is passing as params.

```
User.where(primary_partner_id: 2).map{|a| a.sima}.reject{ |e| e.to_s.empty?}
```

Results as below:

```
 [
    #<Sima id: 93, user_id: 7, interviewer_account_user_id: 1945, interviewer_completion_date: "2017-06-09", transcriber_account_user_id: nil, transcriber_completion_date: nil, biographer_account_user_id: nil, biographer_completion_date: nil, reviewer_account_user_id: nil, reviewer_completion_date: nil, status: "accepted", autobiographical_form: "27381", autobiographical_form_completion_date: nil, sima_level_id: "1", created_at: "2017-06-06 20:17:57", updated_at: "2017-06-09 10:04:33", autobiographical_form_comments: nil, on_hold: nil, comments: [{:comment=>"easylims.xlsx", :user_name=>"Mike Burns", :created_at=>2017-06-06 20:17:57 UTC}, {:comment=>"ok", :user_name=>"SIMA Admin", :created_at=>2017-06-06 20:19:33 UTC}], interviewer_id: nil, interviewer_start_date: nil, transcriber_start_date: nil, biographer_start_date: nil, reviewer_start_date: nil>, 
    #<Sima id: 92, user_id: 1, interviewer_account_user_id: nil, interviewer_completion_date: nil, transcriber_account_user_id: nil, transcriber_completion_date: nil, biographer_account_user_id: nil, biographer_completion_date: nil, reviewer_account_user_id: nil, reviewer_completion_date: nil, status: "accepted", autobiographical_form: "27437", autobiographical_form_completion_date: nil, sima_level_id: "1", created_at: "2017-06-06 20:01:50", updated_at: "2017-06-06 20:22:50", autobiographical_form_comments: nil, on_hold: nil, comments: [{:comment=>"original_msg (1).txt", :user_name=>"bild_cloud@bild.org", :created_at=>2017-06-06 20:01:50 UTC}, {:comment=>"ok", :user_name=>"SIMA Admin", :created_at=>2017-06-06 20:22:05 UTC}], interviewer_id: nil, interviewer_start_date: nil, transcriber_start_date: nil, biographer_start_date: nil, reviewer_start_date: nil>
 ]
```

Sima has field like status and I have three statuses as "pending, accepted, declined"

### Question:

Now I want to show the result as per status which will pass by the user as params. So the result should be as per status from Sima. If params is status=" accepted" then Sima list will have only which has status "accepted"

Comment: Do you have any relation between sima and statuses?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, If you see the results that will tell you status is a field in Sima. Tx

Comment: ```User.joins(:sima).where({primary_partner_id: params[:account_id], sima: {status: params[:status]}})```

Comment: Frankly speaking you already have account to user relation as well...you can just do ```account.users.joins(:sima).where(sima: {status: params[:status]})```

Comment: That would return users. I think he wants `Sima` records.

Comment: OP never mentioned what actually he wants...I thought he wants the user list which has sima status as specified...

Comment: @Kirandixit as per your new edit I think you can go for @aBadAssCowboy's answer...or ```account.users.joins(:sima).where(sima: {status: params[:status]}).map{|a| a.sima}```

Comment: This will make as many database calls as Simas are there. Which means, if 10 users having one Sima each match the criteria,  it will make 10 database calls

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Please check my all statements, I have mentioned what I need.  I am talking about Sima only

Answer (score 1):

By doing this you can avoid N+1 Query problem

```
User.includes(:sima).where(sima: {status: params[:status]},primary_partner_id: params[:account_id]).map(&:sima)
```

If you are using **joins** --> In map statement each time query will be called so that we are preferred to use includes, for more Information

you can refer this link

**http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html**

Answer (score 0):

With the same associations you have on the models, you could do (assuming that user passes `status` they wants to see:

```
user_ids = User.where(primary_partner_id: 2).pluck(:id)
Sima.where(user_id: user_ids, status: params[:status])
```

The above will hit the database twice but that's totally fine. You could use `includes` and `map` but I don't think that will be a huge performance benefit depending on the number of users on a account you have. Eitherways, here it is:

```
User.includes(:sima)
  .references(:sima) # you need this if you use Rails 4 +
  .where(users: { primary_partner_id: 2 })
  .where(simas: { status: params[:status] })
  .map(&:sima)
```

However, I suggest you update Account model with has_many through associations.

```
class Account
  has_many :users
  has_many :simas, through: :users
end

# To get sima of a particular status
Account.find(2).simas.where(status: param[:status])
```

This way, you can just do `account.simas` to get simas from all the users that belong to that account.

Comment: User has_one sima as I said. Above second solution will not be work right? you added has_many :(

Comment: @aBadAssCowboy
Is it possible to refactor first one for performance and small query?

Comment: @Kirandixit have you tried the second solution? User has one Sima but an Account can have multiple Sima through multiple user. So it should work.

Comment: Yes, I can update to use single query but I wouldn't say it will be a small query. It will be a bigger one depending on how many users etc. The first one is performance wise pretty good with two queries too. I will anyway update it

Comment: @aBadAssCowboy second solution I have tried but that is not working. First one is working. Tx

Comment: @aBadAssCowboy Just includes wont work I think you should do join as well

Comment: @VamsiKrishna It does. Reference: https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

Comment: @Kirandixit If the solutions worked, considering accepting the answer.

Comment: ```If you want to add conditions to your included models you’ll have to explicitly reference them``` In the same referred article...

Comment: Yes. that is needed. Good point. My bad. I still use a Rails 3 app.

Answer (score 0):

You could join the simas model and the user model

```
User.joins("JOIN simas ON simas.user_id = users.id")
    .where(primary_partner_id: 2, "simas.status": 'accepted')
    .map{|a| a.sima}
```

Comment: You can just specify ```User.joins(:sima)``` Rails will do an Inner join as there is a has_one relationship between user and sima...

Answer (score 0):

As I am understanding your above all statements. End user us passing account id and you want to take sima status from the end user as well.

You can file all users id from account first. then find sima which will belong to that user and here you can pass sima status as well.

@aBadAssCowboy given the correct answer which is first one only. But from that query, you will get all Sima either nil or with value.

```
user_ids = User.where(primary_partner_id: params[:account_id]).pluck(:id)
Sima.where(user_id: user_ids, status: params[:status]).reject{ |e| e.to_s.empty?}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
User.preload(:sima).joins(:sima).where(sima: {status: params[:status]}, primary_partner_id: params[:account_id]).map(&:sima)
```

or

As account to users relationship is already defined you can directly do...

```
Account.find(2).users.preload(:sima).joins(:sima).where(sima: {status: params[:status]}).map(&:sima)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add to Sima Model
`belongs_to :user` You can get an list of Sima by
`Sima.joins(:users).where(users: { primary_partner_id: 2 }).where(status: 'accepted')`